# How would we know whether a object is moving in deep space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, relative-motion

In deep space, there isn't anything we can compare our position with (According to my knowledge). In other words, we won't be able to define an origin so how would we know whether we are in motion or not?

Comment: Try searching web for "CMB dipole".

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to know if we are moving at constant speed in a straight line in space or at rest in space because there is no such thing as "absolute" motion.

An object in space (or anywhere, for that matter) can be moving at constant speed in a straight line with respect to one inertial (non accelerating) observer and be at rest with respect to another inertial (non accelerating) observer.  The observers would not agree as to whether or not the object is in motion. The only thing the two observers would agree upon is that since the observed object is not accelerating, it is not being subjected to a net external force, per Newtons laws of motion.

Hope this helps.